# trying to z-index subnav behind background

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, z-index

So I am trying to create a dropdown navigation that pops out from behind a background image. I figured the best way to do this is with z-index, but I cannot seem to get this to work... Here is the link, take a look and you will see what I am looking to do: http://cottonwood.towermarketing.net/. Basically when you hover over the top-nav items, I want the sub-nav to slide out from behind the torn parchment paper. I have been struggling with this for a bit now. Below is my CSS and HTML, if more is needed I can post more. Any help would be amazing!

CSS:

```
.header {
    background: url(../../assets/images/repeatable-tear.png) repeat-x;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%
}

.top-nav {
    z-index: 1  
}

.sub-nav {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    margin:0 0 0 -1px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    background: #4e8abe;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="top-nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="top-nav"><a href="#">One</a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="top-nav"><a href="#">Two</a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                         <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ok, with some of the comments i changed it to this, but I can only get the entire nav to go behind, not just the sub nav:

CSS
    .header {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%
    }

```
.header-bg {
    background: url(../../assets/images/repeatable-tear.png) repeat-x;
    height: 175px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-bg"></div>
    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="top-nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="top-nav"><a href="#">One</a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="top-nav"><a href="#">Two</a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the sub-navigation menus outside of the header element.  Right now they are in the same stacking context as the header (where the background is located) so they will just display on top of the background image regardless of your z-index value.

Comment: I just tried taking the bg off of .header and added an empty div of .header-bg directly inside of .header and put the same styles on it. I can now make the entire nav go behind it, but not just the subnav. getting closer. Thanks

Comment: try something like this <div class="bg-header">TOP NAV MENU HTML HERE</div><div class="subnaviagation-container">SUB NAV HTML HERE</div>

Comment: I see where you are going with this, but I cannot seem to get this concept to work... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your hierarchy. The background element and the drop-down element should both be on the same level. The fact that the background element *contains* the drop-down element, you will not be able to z-index it into oblivion. Applying your background to `div.header-container`, and then shifting `div.nav` up one level (out of of `div.header-container`, into `div.header`), you will be able to remedy this issue. Of course, after the aid of some positioning, you'll be able to achieve exactly what you're aiming for.

Comment: I edited the HTML and CSS to the above. Getting closer... Thanks!